# Sqlite data don't show after close the apps

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my MainActivity.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
EditText etName, etEmail;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
Button save;

// declare view
ListView lvEmployees;
// declare adapter
CustomizedAdapter adapter;

// datasource

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    lvEmployees = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEmployees);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            save(v);

        }
    });

}

public void save(View v) {
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

    Employee employee = new Employee(name, email);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), employee.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    long inserted = dbHelper.insertEmployee(employee);
    if (inserted >= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data inserted",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data insertion failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    ArrayList<Employee> employees = dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
    if (employees != null && employees.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new CustomizedAdapter(this, employees);
        lvEmployees.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

}

This is my DataBaseHelper.

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "task_management";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "employee";
public static final String ID_FIELD = "_id";
public static final String NAME_FIELD = "name";
public static final String EMAIL_FIELD = "email";


public static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "
        + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + " (" + ID_FIELD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + NAME_FIELD + " TEXT, " + EMAIL_FIELD + " DATETIME);";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // create tables
    db.execSQL(EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL);
    Log.e("TABLE CREATE", EMPLOYEE_TABLE_SQL);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // upgrade logic

}

// insert
public long insertEmployee(Employee emp) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME_FIELD, emp.getName());
    values.put(EMAIL_FIELD, emp.getEmail());
    long inserted = db.insert(EMPLOYEE_TABLE, null, values);

    db.close();
    return inserted;
}

// query
public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    ArrayList<Employee> allEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // String[] columns={NAME_FIELD, EMAIL_FIELD, PHONE_FIELD};
    // SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(EMPLOYEE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE", null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            //
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_FIELD));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(NAME_FIELD));
            String email = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(EMAIL_FIELD));
            Employee e = new Employee(id, name, email);
            allEmployees.add(e);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return allEmployees;
}
```

}

When i put data and pressed the save button then my data is saved and show in my ListView.
But when i close the apps and open it then i don't see any data in my ListView.
After putting data and pressed save button my new and existing data show in my ListView.
So how can i show my existing data in ListView after open my apps and without press the save button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show data each time app starts, you would need to move your list populating code in `onCreate`

Move this code to `onCreate` instead of Save button's `onClick`

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
if (employees != null && employees.size() > 0) {
    adapter = new CustomizedAdapter(this, employees);
    lvEmployees.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Hope it helps.

P.S: If you need to repopulate list after Save button's click, make a separate function which contains this code. And call tha function in `onCreate` as well as in Save button's `onClick`

Comment: If i move this code to oncreate then if i save my data it don't show.
When i reopen apps then it shows.@MysticMagic

Comment: @RasedurjamanSojib Did you read P.S? I told that you would need to call the same code fro, both places.. in onCreate and in Save method, too :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adapter for the list view in your save method that is called only when you actually press the save button. Here's the part where you do it.

```
    ArrayList<Employee> employees  = dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
    if (employees != null && employees.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new CustomizedAdapter(this, employees);
        lvEmployees.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Thats why there is no data in the listview when you open the app.

You should do this in your onCreate method, and in your save you should do something like this:
1. declare the the arraylist of employees along with listview;

```
 ArrayList<Employee> employees;
```

2. in your oncreate call this code that you should remove from the save method

   ```
       employees  = dbHelper.getAllEmployees();
       if (employees != null && employees.size() > 0) {
           adapter = new CustomizedAdapter(this, employees);
           lvEmployees.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
   ```
3. in save method just add one more item to the list, and notify adapter that there has been a change in the data it's displaying.

   employees.add(employee);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();